# Child graph with plus(), modules override and buildTypes

Tags: dependency-injection, android-gradle-plugin, dagger

What would be an elegant way to create child graphs using `ObjectGraph.plus()` with different modules according to the buildType?
I would like to `ObjectGraph.plus(new ModuleA())` for buildType A and `ObjectGraph.plus(new ModuleB())` for buildType B (with module B overriding module A in my case).
I'm already doing something similar with includes but I can't think of a way to do that with child graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a class in each build type folder which has a static method for listing modules.

```
// In src/release/java:
public class Modules {
  public static Object[] list() {
    return new Object[] {
        new ModuleA()
    };
  }
}
```

---

```
// In src/debug/java:
public class Modules {
  public static Object[] list() {
    return new Object[] {
        new ModuleA(),
        new ModuleB()
    };
  }
}
```

Now when you call `.create()` or `.plus()` you can just delegate to these methods:

```
ObjectGraph.create(Modules.list());
```

You can see a real-world example of this at http://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020